# Django rest framework - TokenAuthentication

Tags: django-rest-framework

The doc says : "REST framework provides a built-in view to provide this behavior. To use it, add the obtain_auth_token view to your URLconf..."

I followed the doc but I can't figure out how to display the ObtainAuthToken view and more generally how to configure TokenAuthentication correctly...

Thanks

Comment: The ObtainAuthToken view gives you an endpoint where you can post a username and password and you'll get back a response of JSON with a token. So try POSTing to that url using curl or postman. As for things to check, make sure your urls.py is setup correctly, make sure you have the DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES set correctly in settings.py and make sure rest_framewrok.authtoken is listed as an installed app. If you're still having issues, you ought to post your urls.py and settings.py (scrubbed of any private info of course).

Comment: Thank your for your help. First, in my settings.py INSTALLED_APPS I have both  'rest_framework', 'rest_framework.authtoken'. Are they mutually exclusive or can I have both methods of authentication?

Comment: Second, for 'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES' I have both 'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication', so same question...

Comment: and finally concerning url.py I have added url(r'^api-token-auth/', 'rest_framework.authtoken.views.obtain_auth_token', name='api-token-auth')

Comment: Your config seems correct to me. What happens if you POST a username and password to the api-token-auth url?

Comment: I receive this "token": "448830b172f33f927500e34db4ff2f3fb8b34d90"

Comment: Well that's good. Was there anything in particular that you did to fix it? Perhaps something you could craft into an answer in case someone else ends up with the same problem? Or was it just a misunderstanding of the ObtainAuthToken view?

Comment: Yes I think it was a misunderstanding on my side; by view I expected to see a web gui. Your hint helped me a lot to make the right test. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

`url(r'^api-token-auth/', 'rest_framework.authtoken.views.obtain_auth_token')`

That takes a view provided by Django Rest Framework and makes it available at "api-token-auth". That goes in your "urls.py" file.